# How to upload application data such as pdf files,sqlite file,images,notes on icloud and sync with application data?

Tags: ios

how to upload application data such as pdf files,sqlite file,images,notes on icloud and autosync icloud with application data.i have tried raywenderlich tutorial. but unable to upload the files to icloud. any help is appreciated.